# Get Set and carrying value from Controller to VF page isn't working

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I want to lookup the current SupportTier field in Account object according to the user that is logged in and pass it to the VF page. For some reason it is not working correctly. Getting a "Variable not exist" error.

Controller >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
    public String GetSupportTierValue {
  get {
    if( GetSupportTierValue == null ) {
       String SupportTier = [SELECT Id, Name, Support_Tier__c
                       FROM Account
                       WHERE Id IN 
                            (SELECT AccountId 
                               FROM user 
                              WHERE username=:UserInfo.getUsername()
                             )
                       LIMIT 1
                     ].Support_Tier__c;

       SupportTierValue = SupportTier;
    }
    return SupportTierValue;
  }
  set { SupportTierValue = SupportTier; }

}
```

VisualForce Page >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
var GetSupportTierValue = '{!GetSupportTierValue}';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `getter/setter` then do not specify `get` in the attribute name.

You can change it like this way:

```
public String SupportTierValue {
  get {
    if( SupportTierValue == null ) {
       String SupportTier = [SELECT Id, Name, Support_Tier__c
                       FROM Account
                       WHERE Id IN 
                            (SELECT AccountId 
                               FROM user 
                              WHERE username=:UserInfo.getUsername()
                             )
                       LIMIT 1
                     ].Support_Tier__c;

       SupportTierValue = SupportTier;
    }
    return SupportTierValue;
  }
  set {}

}
```

visualforce:

```
var GetSupportTierValue = '{!SupportTierValue}';
```

For more information, refer [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Comment: Thank you Santanu, I did just like you said. Now I am getting this error: "Compile Error: Variable does not exist: SupportTier"   - its in the Set { line

Comment: dont set anything in Set